# How can the value of the http variable of type get be preserved after the page is refreshed

Tags: php, get

I am working on developing an e-learning platform, in which there is a page for the professor, and on the page of the professor there is a link. When you click on it, the page goes to add content and this link carries the id of the study material through the get variable. The problem here is that when the page is updated, the value of the variable is separated.

Comment: Are you able to include any of the code for the refresh or link?

Comment: The problem is that I lose the value of the judge after updating the page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without more details and some code to see, but in theory, you can pull the `$_GET` and give it to a $_SESSION variable..

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['getVar'] = $_GET['getVar'];
```

Then it's avaialble so long as the site is being accessed (even refresh).